# Trying to calculate subtotal of the module marks using javascript but responding

Tags: javascript, html

Using javascript to create a page to create the sub-total mark of module to the overall module mark: 
I want to create a function to calculate the subtotal like this

Subtotal = Log1 * 10 /24 + Log2*10/24 +ClassTest*10/50.

I want it to Display the value of  Subtotal and If the Subtotal is less then 12, display: “Merry Christmas and Work harder next semester!” otherwise, display: “Merry Christmas and Keep it up!” but I'm struggling to get the code to work and was wondering why this was the case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>


<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

function doSomething(num1,num2,num3,){


  var numb1 = parseInt(document.myform.num1.value);
  var numb2 = parseInt(document.myform.num2.value);
  var numb3 = parseInt(document.myform.num3.value);

 if (isNaN(numb1)) {
    window.alert("Mark 1 is not a valid number!");
    }
  else if (isNaN(numb2)) {
    window.alert("Mark 2 is not a valid number!");
    }
  else if (isNaN(numb3)) {
    window.alert("Mark 3 is not a valid number!");
    }

  else if (numb1 > 100 || numb2 > 100 || numb3 > 100 ) {
    window.alert("Marks must not be higher than 100!");
        return;
    }
  else if (numb1 < 0 || numb2 < 0 || numb3 < 0  ) {
    window.alert("Marks must not be negative!");
        return;
    } 

  //if…else if…else statement
  log1=numb1*10/24;
  log2=numb2*10/24;
  test=numb3*10/50;
  subtotal = log1+log2+test;



  if (subtotal > 12)
  {
  window.alert( subtotal +"Merry Christmas and Work harder next semester!");

  }

  else if (avg <= 12)
  {
  window.alert(subtotal +"Merry Christmas and Keep it up!”);

  }


</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<p>Please input your marks and click the button to start:</p>

<form name="myform">
<p> Log 1 Mark :</p>
<input type="text" size="10" name="num1">

<p> Log 2 Mark:</p>
<input type="text" size="10" name="num2">

<p> Class Test Mark:</p>
<input type="text" size="10" name="num3">



<br>

<input type="button" name="mybutton" value="Continue" onclick="doSomething(num1,num2,num3);">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "_I'm struggling to get the code to work_" What exactly is not working correctly? Any errors displayed in your console?

Comment: Yes SCRIPT5009: 'doSomething' is undefined

Comment: When you wrote `onclick="doSomething(num1,num2,num3);"` were you trying to send the 3 elements to the function? Or send the 3 names of the elements?

Comment: I think it was the three elements

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (avg <= 12)
```

You're testing a variable that you never define anywhere. Could this be your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of compilation problems

1. you use both `subtotal` and `average`, whereas `average` is not defined
2. Your function accepts some arguments but does not use them
3. A fixed example is below (ensure that `document.myform.num1.value` works as expected

As a tip, simply open your [Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) to spot these errors

```
function doSomething() {
    var numb1 = parseInt(document.myform.num1.value);
    var numb2 = parseInt(document.myform.num2.value);
    var numb3 = parseInt(document.myform.num3.value);

    if (isNaN(numb1)) {
        window.alert("Mark 1 is not a valid number!");
        return;
    }
    else if (isNaN(numb2)) {
        window.alert("Mark 2 is not a valid number!");
        return;
    }
    else if (isNaN(numb3)) {
        window.alert("Mark 3 is not a valid number!");
        return;
    }
    else if (numb1 > 100 || numb2 > 100 || numb3 > 100) {
        window.alert("Marks must not be higher than 100!");
        return;
    }
    else if (numb1 < 0 || numb2 < 0 || numb3 < 0) {
        window.alert("Marks must not be negative!");
        return;
    }

    //if…else if…else statement
    var log1 = numb1 * 10 / 24;
    var log2 = numb2 * 10 / 24;
    var test = numb3 * 10 / 50;
    var subtotal = log1 + log2 + test;

    if (subtotal > 12) {
        window.alert(subtotal + "Merry Christmas and Work harder next semester!");
    }
    else if (subtotal <= 12) {
        window.alert(subtotal + "Merry Christmas and Keep it up!”);

    }
}
```